# SimpleSAMLPHP http-post bindings on safari

Tags: safari, saml, simplesamlphp

I have a SimpleSAMLPHP SP set up to an external Idp (different server and domains) that only supports HTTP-POST binding

Everything works fine on most platforms but Safari is not working properly.

It looks like Safari simply does not POST the SAML data, and only redirects the user to the "Location"

anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: That SAML response POSTing is done by javascript usually. So I would check POSTing HTML page for any JS errors.

Comment: the response POST? or the request? what I can summarize is that the SAML data is simply not received by iDP

Comment: Be more familiar with SAML. I guess your SP generates SAML request and IDP generated SAML response (I don't see `SAML data is simply not received by iDP` in the SAML flow). Use SAML tracer extension in the Firefox to explore how SAML request/response looks like in your case.